# How to disabled Viber running without uninstalling it?

Tags: viber-messenger

How do I stop Viber running, without uninstalling the app? When I go Menu→More options→Exit it just comes back. I want it to turn it off completely, so it's not waiting to come on in the background.

Comment: Please do not copy paste questions. If the existing answers do not work, earn some reputation points and offer a bounty on the original question. Visit [help] to know more.